# LINK: fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_program_options.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, cmake, visual-studio-2010

I am using the Boost library for one of my image processing tasks. When I try to build the program using MSVC++ 10, I get the following error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_program_options.lib'
```

CMake, however, does not show any error & works just fine. I am using Boost 1.55.0. Now I searched for the file **boost_program_options.lib** in **C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0** but there was no such file. Please tell me what I should do to get my program working. My CMakeLists.txt file contains the following lines:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS REQUIRED)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    MESSAGE("Boost v1.55 found.")
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ELSE ()
    MESSAGE("Boost not found.")
    SET(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost)
ENDIF()
SET(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib)
```

and

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(RegionCompetition main.cxx)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MyProject boost_program_options ${ITK_LIBRARIES})
```

If this has already been answered, please redirect me there. I did not find the answer to this question, however.

Comment: You did build the boost libraries right?

Comment: Are you trying to use cmake with msvc+10?

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, there are .lib files in C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib, all of them starting with the prefix 'libboost-'. bjam told me to add that directory to Library Directories in VC++. I wonder if 'libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-1_55.lib' is equivalent to boost_program_options.lib'?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I suppose you mean MSVC++ 10? Yes.

Comment: @Captain_Haddock, no, they are not equal, but I am lost as to why you would use VC++ and cmake. Are you trying to generate the VS project out of cmake or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @LaszloPapp Yes I'm generating the VS project using cmake. I am also using ITK, so using cmake is recommended (or so they say).

Comment: @Captain_Haddock: please show the boost dependency handling in your cmake file. Does it work with nmake from command line though?

Answer (score 0):

From boost1.33, the boost_program_options.lib has been changed to libboost_program_options-mt.dylib for multithread. You maybe use this new lib.

Comment: There is a file called libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-1_55.lib in my stage\lib directory. I tried using it, but no luck. I did not find any file called libboost_program_options-mt.dylib, though. Can you tell me where is it?